# C# .NET WebForms CKEditor to SQL potentially dangerous Request.Form value

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, webforms, ckeditor

I have the dreaded `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

CKEDitor jquery instance. Initiating CKEditor onto a multiline asp:textbox. On submit I'm using ADO.net to save out to SQL database.

I know I can use pages `validateRequest="false"` but I also know that will leave me vulnerable. I know what boxes are trying to save the HTML, things keep saying to "HTML Encode" some how. I have tried the config - `config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;` and I have tried `Server.HTMLEncode` on the text value. Both of which rendering the same error.

Help